# How to fix "warning: overriding the module target triple with x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [-Woverride-module]"

Tags: llvm

How do I fix the following warning produced by `clang` when compiling LLVM code?

```
$ clang test.ll
warning: overriding the module target triple with x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [-Woverride-module]
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the LLVM IR code doesn't explicitly specify a compilation target. To fix it, specify the [`target triple`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#target-triple) at the top of your `.ll` file, for example:

```
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
```

Be sure to replace `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` with the target shown in your warning message. (You can also get the target by running `llvm-config --host-target`.)